# RadGrid Edit Update not Posting Back

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid, radgrid

I have a `RadGrid` that pops in a `RadWindow` when I try to edit and update the changes, the window doesn't postback. The following error shows on the `Update' link:

```
javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TabPanel7$EditPORadWindow$C$EditPORadGrid$ctl00$ctl05$UpdateButton", "", true, "", "", false, true))
```

If you want to see the full code, it has been posted on the other forum:

[RadGrid with RadComboBox not posting back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381173/radgrid-with-radcombobox-not-posting-back)

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out the problem with the `RadGrid` not updating while in `EditMode`.

The culprit was the `Validation`. I had to set the following:

Snippet of the `RadGrid` ASP Code:

```
</MasterTableView>
    <ValidationSettings EnableModelValidation="false" EnableValidation="false" ValidationGroup="10" />
    <PagerStyle PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox" />
    <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False">
```

Now it is updating but the `EditMode` is not exiting to the `RadGrid`...

Comment: Thank you, have been looking for an answer a long time :( This fixed it!